# How to migrate Refinery CMS to CentOs 5.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, refinerycms

I am new to Ruby on Rails.

I have built a demo site with Refinery CMS on my Mac environment and am ready to deploy it to my Virtual Dedicated Server running CentOS 5.x.

Can anyone walk me through the steps to deploy Refinery CMS on my server?

NOTE: I have successfully installed Ruby, Rails (correct versions to Refinery specs) and all the needed gems including Passenger.

I simply cannot figure out how to make the site work on my server.  I would really appreciate some help on this as documentation is difficult to come by, I have already spent over $100 on books and they are of no help.

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Can you please post more details about what isn't working? Also, are you running SELinux? How did you install Ruby?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not ready for this yet.. I am not receiving any errors, but the site doesn't come up when I visit the domain where the site is hosted.  I am thinking I need to do something different in regards to configuration.  I will finish my Ruby book if nobody can help without me having any further knowledge of the install process.  I am simply not an IT guy, I am a PHP/JavaScript developer and am diving into Ruby.. Guess it won't do me much good if I can't figure out how to deploy a ruby site on my server.  I installed Ruby following a blog I found. running 1.9.2

Comment: Try looking at the apache log to see if apache even sees your requests. For CentOS it's on `/var/log/httpd/access_log`

Comment: What you've gotten yourself into is a bit of IT work. You need to do at least the following: 1. Configure the domain (perhaps a vhost) for your http server, probably apache. This includes setting up the required directories for the domain such as httpdocs, logs, and perhaps a separate directory for deployment. 2. Install passenger following their docs for your http server. After passenger is installed, tell apache/passenger that your domain is serving a rails app. 3. Deploy your application. -- You might want to checkout refinery's hosted solutions as an alternative to all that.